# "Application failed codesign verifications" Phonegap build app failed to upload to App Store

Tags: ios, cordova, codesign, phonegap-build

Ive developed an app using Phonegap. I could build the app for testing using development certificate. And the app works fine.

Now i want to upload the app to app store. But im getting an error saying

"Application fialed codesign verification. The signature was failed, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Certificate."

[image]

Comment: Looks like you tried to build the app with `iPhone Developer Certificate` instead `iPhone Distribution Certificate`. Check `Build Settings` tab

Comment: I used the `Distribution certificate & Distribution Provisioning Profile`. But still it says so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling lots of time i found the solution. Refer the link for more details - >[Click here](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/app_store_submission_application_failed_codesign_verification?page=1)

> One thing to note is that please also make sure to export the .p12 by selecting the certificate associated with the key and not the key. (this ensures we have the correct common name and a valid certificate)

This was the root of problem. It might help someone someday.